# Table manipulation

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have three files with genome coordinates and last column as common names

File 1.

```
X 1 100 B
Y 101 200 B
Z 1 50 B
```

File 2.

```
X 200 300 A 
Y 101 200 A
Z 1 50 A
```

File 3.

```
X 1 100 C
Y 200 300 C
Z 1 50 C
```

I would like to manipulate my data according to last column

```
Name Value1 Value2 A B C
X 1 100 No Yes Yes
X 200 300 Yes No No
Y 101 200 Yes Yes No
Y 200 300 No No Yes
Z 1 50 Yes Yes Yes
```

.. Like this.

Would you able to help?

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk 'function get_mask(keys){ 
         mask=""; 
         for(i in h) { 
             res=(keys~i)?"Yes":"No"; mask=(mask!="")? mask FS res:res 
         } 
         return mask 
     }
     { k=$1 FS $2 FS $3 }{ h[$4]; a[k]=(a[k])? a[k]$4:$4 }
     END{ 
         h_line=""; for(i in h) h_line=(h_line=="")? i:h_line FS i;
         printf "Name Value1 Value2 %s\n",h_line;
         for(j in a) printf "%s %s\n", j, get_mask(a[j]) 
     }' file{1,2,3}
```

The output:

```
Name Value1 Value2 A B C
Z 1 50 Yes Yes Yes
Y 101 200 Yes Yes No
Y 200 300 No No Yes
X 1 100 No Yes Yes
X 200 300 Yes No No
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Roman's answer, but I think a little simpler

```
gawk '
    { key = $1 FS $2 FS $3; names[$NF] = 1; has_name[key][$4] = 1 }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        printf "Name Value1 Value2"
        for (v in names) printf " %s", v
        print ""
        for (key in has_name) {
            printf "%s", key
            for (v in names) printf " %s", has_name[key][v] ? "Yes" : "No"
            print ""
        }
    }
' file{1,2,3}
```

```
Name Value1 Value2 A B C
X 1 100 No Yes Yes
X 200 300 Yes No No
Y 101 200 Yes Yes No
Y 200 300 No No Yes
Z 1 50 Yes Yes Yes
```

Uses the GNU awk `PROCINFO` variable to [control array traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning) in sorted order.